# Cумма цифр на километровых столбах

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача:
На каждом километре шоссе между селами Петино и Васино стоит столб с табличкой, на одной стороне которой написано, сколько километров до Петино, а на другой – до Васино. Тимофей заметил, что на каждом столбе сумма всех цифр равна N. Найдите расстояние от Петино до Васино.

```
Алгоритм принимает на вход 1 число - сумму цифр на километровых столбах (N).
На выход алгоритм должен отдавать 1 число - расстояние между Петино и Васино.
```

```
num = int(input())
def g(x):
    y = []
    for i in range(x+1):
        n = x - i
        y.append(sum([int(j) for j in str(i)]) + sum([int(j) for j in str(n)]))
    
    if min(y) == max(y) and min(y) == num:
        return x
    return 0

for i in range(2021): # но тут максимально 2021 километр
    if g(i): print(i); break
    else: g(i)
```

Как еще можно написать программу чтобы число итераций было больше 2021

Comment: Добавьте входные данные и ожидаемый результат

Comment: `for i in range(2021)` замените  `for i in range(2**64)`, получите 18446744073709551616 итераций, если не выполнится условие

Answer (score 2):

Если чуть-чуть покумекать, то можно заметить, **какие именно расстояния** могут давать одинаковые суммы цифр, увидеть закономерности, и получить простую функцию:

```
def dist(x):
     return (x % 9 + 1) * (10**(x // 9)) - 1
```